# dpkg-deb build ignores/misinterprets a changelog

Tags: dpkg, deb

I'm building a .deb package using:

```
dpkg-deb --build package
```

The directory "package" contains another directory called DEBIAN that has the changelog, but the resulting package doesn't have the changelog.Debian.gz in it, and if I check the package using lintian I get following errors:

```
E: msodbcsql: debian-changelog-file-missing
W: msodbcsql: unknown-control-file changelog
```

I don't know if relevant but the permissions on the changelog are as follows:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 maximk maximk  159 May 10 11:23 changelog
```

Why is the "changelog" considered to be an unknown control file instead of, you know, a changelog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a binary package, the changelog isn’t a control file, it’s just part of the package’s payload. With `dpkg-deb -b`, that means you need to place the changelog in `usr/share/doc/${package}/changelog.Debian.gz` directly (or `.../changelog.gz` for a native package).

More explicitly, since you’re building your package in the `package` directory, instead of putting your changelog in `package/DEBIAN/changelog`, you put it in `package/usr/share/doc/package/changelog.Debian.gz`, and build your package as before with `dpkg-deb -b package`.

In source packages, the changelog goes in `debian/changelog` and is processed by `dh_installchangelogs`.

Comment: So first I create the .deb and then add the file to it?

Comment: No, you place the changelog in `package/usr/share/doc/package` and create the `.deb` with `dpkg-deb -b package`.

Comment: Or better yet, check out how to build a package from source, it’s not that difficult ;-).

Comment: Alright, thanks, that worked, although I was getting a wrong-name-for-changelog-of-native-package for changelog.Debian.gz, but it didn't complain about changelog.gz

Comment: Ah, right, you didn’t mention it was a native package. `changelog.gz` is indeed appropriate in that case.